# Insert values into pandas datafrmae based on MUltiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"index": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"], "id": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "name": ["jim", "jim", "jim", "bob", "bob", "bob"], "date":['12/5/1999','12/6/1999','18/4/2000','12/4/2006','14/9/2007','16/4/2008']}).set_index("index")
```

It represents people tow which events occurred at different times. I want to add
a new column, date_order, that sequentially increments a new value to each row within each index, according to the date on which the event occured.
each event occurred. That is, each person would have a date order value assigned in the order the event occurred, starting at 1 and increasing at each older event.

This is what I want to end up with.

```
index   id  name    date        date_order
a       1   jim     12/5/1999   3
a       2   jim     12/6/1999   2
a       3   jim     18/4/2000   1
b       4   bob     12/4/2006   3
b       5   bob     14/9/2007   2
b       6   bob     16/4/2008   1
```

I started by adding a date_order column this `data['date_order'] = 1` and then I tought I could increment over with an iterator using a lambda function and the map function.

This did not work out well for me.

A general kick in the right direction to do this would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea that use an index with duplicate values. Here is the solution if you don't call `.set_index("index")` for your `DataFrame` object.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"], "id": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "name": ["jim", "jim", "jim", "bob", "bob", "bob"], "date":['12/5/1999','12/6/1999','18/4/2000','12/4/2006','14/9/2007','16/4/2008']})
df["date_order"] = df.groupby(df["index"]).date.transform(pd.Series.rank, ascending=False)
```